# Office.js on Outlook for Mac: Internal Error on saveAsync method

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-web-addins, outlook-for-mac

So office.js add-in support is finally out for Outlook for Mac since version 15.32.
I'm actually using the latest non-insider version 15.33, and have one issue that doesn't take place on OWA or Outlook Desktop for Windows.

When I make following call in the add-in to get the event id:

```
const itemCompose = Office.cast.item.toItemCompose(Office.context.mailbox.item);
itemCompose.saveAsync((result) => console.log(result));
```

on OWA and Outlook Windows result.value has the event id, however on Outlook for Mac that is the result:

```
{
 error: Error {name: "Internal Error", message: "An internal error has occurred.", code: 5001}
 status: "failed"
 value: null
}
```

is it a bug in the freshly released office.js support for Outlook for Mac, or I'm doing something wrong?

**important note**: it happens only if the event has some attendees, that is, if the event is an meeting. On an appointment, so an event without attendees, it works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outlook for Mac doesn't support saving a meeting in compose mode, so this is expected. The Mac Outlook team knows about it.

Comment: Are there any plans to add support for this function? It complicates our support for Outlook for Mac, with that function it would be ready to release.

Comment: Yes, this is in their backlog to fix. I don't have a timeframe to give at this point though.

Comment: @JasonJohnston Do you know if there any kind of update on this issue?

Comment: @JasonJohnston can you point to this backlog issue? is it public?